# Replicate part of production django database to local or staging

Tags: python, django, database, development-environment, wagtail

I have a Django website with 3 environments (Local, Staging, Production).

Production contains some data that I don't want my developers to have access to (Personal data and financial data of users).

Doing a DB backup restore is not an option for compliance reason.

However we also have some content pages on this website that we manage with Wagtail CMS.

I am looking for a way to sync production data (only some models but specifically the wagtail pages) back to Staging and Developers local environment when they need to.

Ideally I would have a manage command that I can run in another environment to copy data:

Example: `./manage.py sync_from_prod BlogPost` this would find all missing blog post in the local or staging environment and would create them in the database. I cannot find any library doing this for Wagtail or Django doing this.

This seems like a common problem and I am surprised to find no Stackoverflow questions or opensource libraries fixing this problem.

If nothing exist I will probably try to write my own django-model-sync (Found this project, but is 3 year old and compatible until django 1.7 and I am on python3 django 1.11)

In order to manage security, a secret could be used by a dev to access a production API exposing the data (over ssl) for example

Comment: 5 years later I am going to explain how I do it now: My database is in CloudSQL (google) I have a github action that download the dump of prod load it inside a local DB, execute a manage command that cleans the data and remove the PII then dump it on Google Cloud storage bucket where the devs can download it and load it locally.

Answer (score 4):

You can use command `dumpdata` for your models you want to copy.

Use in production command `./manage.py dumpdata app_name.model_name > model_name.json`. That will save all data of chose db table in file `model_name.json`. 
Then use `loaddata` on local or stage server for this file:
`./manage.py loaddata model_name.json`.

You can read more about this here: https://the-bosha.ru/2016/06/29/django-delaem-damp-bazy-dannykh-i-vosstanavlivaem-iz-nego-s-dumpdata-i-loaddata/
*(Russian instruction only)*

Comment: I got error messages upon loading. I looked it up and I think the correct way of using dumpdata is with "--output" rather than ">"
./manage.py dumpdata app_name.model_name --output model_name.json

Answer (score 2):

I struggled mightily with the dumpdata / loaddata and had to assemble the answer from various sources, so I'll write a short summary of what worked for me in the end:

1. On Prod: `./manage.py dumpdata -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --output data.json`
2. On Dev: flush your database `./manage.py flush`, if flushing does not work, see below
3. On Dev: `./manage.py loaddata data.json`

If flush does not work due to some data inconsistency on Dev which happened to me:

1. delete the db file
2. delete everything except the initials from the migrations folder `rm */migrations/0*.py`
3. ./manage.py migrations && ./manage.py migrate

Then you should be able to load the data

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you can make use of `dumpdata` command (or extending the command) in prod to get the JSON export of the blog data and then use `loaddata` command locally to save into your local environment.

How to implement the workflow is completely up to you, eg. you might want to wrap the `dumpdata` command in an protected API on prod, then create/run a `sync_from_prod` command in your local env to call that api and execute the `call_command('loaddata', 'data_file.json')` command with JSON exported data from prod.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
# the api view to provide the data on prod
def dumpdata_view(requst):
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    call_command('dumpdata', output=output)
    output.seek(0)
    return JsonResponse(output.readlines()

# command to execute locally
class sync_from_prod(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with open('data_file.json', 'w') as f:
            data = requests.get('https://prod/api/dumpdata?model=BlogPost')
            f.write(data.content)
        call_command('loaddata', 'data_file.json')
```

Comment: The problem with dump data is that you have no control on the data that you get (no filter, no hooks for transforming personal identifying data points).

Comment: I was under the context that you want to sync the BlogPost from prod only. The obfuscating data part is a separate issue.